# Loop vba display various emails at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Im compressing a file in parts of 10MB with WINRAR. I want to loop and create 1 email attaching each part and display all the emails before send them.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
For i = 1 To times
    With OutMail
        .To = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(4, 3).Value
        .CC = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(5, 3).Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(6, 3).Value
        .Body = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(9, 3).Value
        'You can add other files also like this

            If (times > 1) Then
                .Attachments.Add source & "part" & i & ".rar"
            Else: .Attachments.Add source & "rar"
            End If
        '.Send   'or use .Display

        .Display
    End With
Next i
```

1. If i run it with ".Send" it sends 1 email without anything attached.
2. If i use ".Display" it shows 1 email in outlook ready to send with
   all the parts attached. (3 parts in my example).

I want either:

- To send 3 email with 1 part of the file each atached 
  OR
- Display 3 emails, each one with 1 part attached ready to click "send"
  in Outlook.

I Hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply missed the part where you create a new mail 
`Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)`
**inside the loop**, like this :

```
For i = 1 To times
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(4, 3).value
        .CC = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(5, 3).value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(6, 3).value
        .Body = wb1.Sheets("MAIL").Cells(9, 3).value
        'You can add other files also like this

            If (times > 1) Then
                .Attachments.Add Source & "part" & i & ".rar"
            Else
                .Attachments.Add Source & "rar"
            End If
        '.Send   'or use .Display

        .Display
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: I did it before the code I posted. Sorry for not show it before. Editing main post now. i willl test inside  the loop.

Comment: @AngelMdez : I wasn't clear enough, I knew that you had this line, but it needs to be inside the loop to create multiple mails! ;)

Comment: I test it. For some reason the first time it loops, It doesnt display anything. 2nd and 3rd time It does.

The result is 2 emails with xxxxx.part2.rar and xxxx.part3.rar attached ready to send but no email with xxx.part1.rar.

Comment: @AngelMdez : Very strange that you don't have the part1... Try placing breakpoints or do a step-by-step debug to see how the code flow, but you should have the 1st mail with part1.

Comment: It is very strange indeed. If i start the loop with i = 0 to times, first iteration doesnt creat/display anything and the other 3 does it. That solves it but I still dont know why it happens.

Comment: @AngelMdez : Very strange indeed, I can't think of anything that would cause that... Especially with you waiting 30 seconds for Outlook to open... Anyhow, glad I could help! ;)